# JTabbedPane - keep order of tabs

Tags: java, arrays, collections, jtabbedpane

This problem is not necessarily specific to JTabbedPane, but this is where I came across it. The idea is that you have a list of priorities `Priority[]` according to which you would like to see the output tabs to be rendered. Each tab can have many objects associated with a given priority, and I want to generate the tab as the **first** object is detected for it. The objects are generated by external service and they may come in any order. So, let's say you have

```
[Low, Medium, Warning, Alert, Crash]
```

as your list of priorities. Now, this is what I want to generate

```
[] -> []
[Alert] -> [Alert]
[Alert, Alert] -> [Alert]
[Alert, Alert, Low] -> [Low, Alert]
[Alert, Alert, Low, Medium] -> [Low, Medium, Alert]
```

the RHS is the order of tabs and the LHS is the coming priorities. Any ideas how I can dynamically achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
List<String> priorities = Arrays.asList("Low", "Medium", "Warning", "Alert", "Crash");
Map<List<String>> data = new LinkedHashMap<List<String>>();
for (String priority : priorities)
  data.put(priority, new ArrayList<String>());

...
```

Incoming data:

```
String priority = ...;

List<String> list = data.get(priority);
list.add("my new data");

if (list.size() == 1) {
  //insert tab
  int index = 0;
  int priorityIndex = priorities.indexOf(priority);
  while (priorityIndex > priorities.indexOf(tabbedPaned.getTitleAt(index))) {
    index++;
  }
  tabbedPane.insertTab(priority, ... , index); //includes index where to insert the tab
}

//update tabs
...
```

Comment: yes, I get that all, how do I find the index at which to place it? that is the whole trick I am missing

Comment: I think you should refine your question then to ask for the index. There are several way, one easy way is to use the title of the tabs. r just store that info in a separate data structure. Updating my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can call the insertTab method on your JTabbedPane to insert your new tab at the specified position.

```
    insertTab(title, icon, panel, title, index);
```

So you can loop through each tab and insert it at the specified index based on the priority.

Comment: what do you mean by "loop through tabs"?

Comment: not sure what your requirements are but can tabs be added on the fly or will they all be added at once e.g. when the page loads?